# EmberJS: How to display numbered items each row in a table?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a list of items and I want it to be displayed in a table. In handlebars docs, it says that I can access the `@index` to display the index of each item. However, in ember.js, it seems to have an error with @index.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
<tbody>
    {{#each}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{@index}}</td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

you can use {{_view.contentIndex}} instead. Preview: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/panoseya/1/edit

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked. But how can I add 1 to the index? I tried _view.contentIndex + 1 but didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't work out of the box, you'll need to register a Handlebars helper. Preview: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/panoseya/3/edit